# How to convert String to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json

I need your help about retreive data from mysql db. I cant add string to array list.
my list declare

```
ArrayList<HandleListReport> reportList = new ArrayList<HandleListReport>();
```

here my code

```
report_data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_REPORT_DATA);

                    for (int i = 0; i < report_data.length(); i++) {

                        //storing variable
                        JSONObject c = report_data.getJSONObject(i);
                        String reportID = c.getString(TAG_REPORT_ID);
                        String userID = c.getString(TAG_UID);
                        String projectName = c.getString(TAG_PROJECT_NAME);
                        String localWork = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                        String timeStart = c.getString(TAG_TIME_START);
                        String timeEnd = c.getString(TAG_TIME_END);
                        Log.d(TAG_LOCATION, localWork);
                        // add data to Arraylist
                        reportList.add(new HandleListReport(reportID, userID, projectName, localWork, timeStart, timeEnd));
```

my problem my listReport missing string data. Logcat show reportList ---> []

thanks for answer!

Comment: where do you declare reportList. Write here and also what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: my logcat throws [] on reportList

Comment: Have you debugged your code to find the values of your variables
`reportID, userID, projectName, localWork, timeStart, timeEnd` before using them to create the new `HandleListReport` object?

Comment: all variables have value

Comment: Have you verified that those are being set correctly in your `HandleListReport` class?

Comment: reportList isn't `null`, correct? It just doesn't have any values after you add them?

Answer (score 0):

create a list of string

```
List<String> list ......

list.add(String)
```

then   list.toArray() method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to store object of HandleListReport in arraylist. In that case use the following to initiate

```
ArrayList<HandleListReport> reportList = new ArrayList<HandleListReport>();
```

Comment: where did you initiate the arraylist? initiate it in oncreate(). and after ending the loop also check the reportList.size()

Comment: It wouldn't have to be in `onCreate()`. As long as it is a member variable then it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the length of variable report_data is 0, so the element does not add the list.